# Epson software update keeps popping up on my screen but nothing gets downloaded

Tags: macos, printing, driver

[image]

I get that question pop-up on my screen a few times per day. Sometimes several times in a row. If I say Yes, a long EULA document appears for me to accept, then a window with a progress bar that reaches about half the way before I get this: [image]

When I go to Software Update, nothing appears in the list. All my software is up to date.

Selecting No closes the dialog but it may reappear again in seconds.

I got tired of this, removed my printer from Print/Scan settings, used Epson uninstaller utility (found on their site) to remove their drivers and software from the system, rebooted the machine, plugged in my printer back and OS X downloaded drivers and installed them again. All was well for about a week. Today this started again. Any insight into fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, only with an HP printer. Every time I plug it in, it asks if I want to download the drivers; I say yes, and then it says they're unavailable. Yet it still prints fine anyway...

Comment: I have a feeling this is somehow related to me using Parallels. Are you using Parallels on your machine by any chance?

Comment: I am! Interesting...

Comment: I'm not using Parallels, but this is happening with my Epson printer (CX7400) every time a user logs in. (There are multiple users on my Mac.) Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 2):

Just talked with Epson support. I had already removed the printer from System Preferences > Print & Scan, but when I tried to add the printer back it said the software could not be found. In talking with Epson this what he had me do:

1. I had already removed the printer so do this first.
2. Open System Preferences > Print & Scan, right-click in the list of printers on the left, and choose "Reset printing system..."
3. Run the Software Update under the Apple menu. (Being Mountain Lion this opened the App Store application. However, there were no software updates for me.)
4. Restart computer.
5. Open System Preferences > Print & Scan and add the printer again.

It was able to add the printer, and now the dialog box in @King Julian's post is not showing for me. Hope this works for others too.